# Use MySQL with Qt on mac

Tags: c++, mysql, database, qt, driver

After 2 days struggling, I couldn't find any well explained way to install Mysql to use with Qt on mac. So I think this could be relevant not only for me.

**Issue is at step 3.**

The steps:

1. Download Qt
   http://qt-project.org/downloads
   choose Online installer.
   When installing don't forget to install Source components of your version!
2. Download Mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/#downloads
   DMG 32 or 64 bits
   When installed open: mysql-5.5.9-osx10.6-x86_64.pkg (numbers will depend of version) and follow steps.
   Open terminal (Applications, Utilities) type:

> cd /usr/local/mysql
>      sudo ./bin/mysqld_safe

enter password if necessary

Press: Ctrl + Z

Type:

> bg

Press: Ctrl + D
Quit Terminal.

It's better to set a Password for after, so do it. Open again terminal an type:

> /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root password YOUR_NEW_PASSWORD

3.Install drivers in Qt

> cd $QTDIR/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql
>   qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/local/include" "LIBS+=-L/usr/local/lib -lmysqlclient_r" mysql.pro
>   make

**STEP 3 does not work** because; as Qt says:

```
You need the MySQL header files and as well as the shared library libmysqlclient.so
```

How do I get those?

> apt-get install mysql-devel

does not work, because I'm on mac, so installed Homebrew, but I'm not able to install with

> brew install libmysqlclient-dev

If someone use/used it on mac, it would be good to build proper information...

Comment: You should look at MacPorts. `sudo port install mysql5-devel` Try [this link](http://www.macports.org) to find out how to install MacPorts

Comment: I achieved to make it work, but definetely not the shortest way. It would be good to show a short and compatible way of doing for any Mac user